# How commonly used / understood is the "BR" signature?

Tags: acronyms

In Finland, in informal correspondence over email in English I often see the acronym "BR" or "Br" used in the signature before the name, and I've seen some people from at least Germany do the same. I believe this is an acronym for "Best Regards", but many acronym lists omit it. [1](https://www.acronymfinder.com/Best-Regards-(BR).html)

How widely used / understood is this acronym? Are there specific geographical regions where it's common? Does usage of it in a signature stand out as weird for some audiences?

Br,
Sampo J.

[1](https://www.acronymfinder.com/Best-Regards-(BR).html) For example [AcronymFinder has it](https://www.acronymfinder.com/Best-Regards-(BR).html) (among 123 alternative definitions), while [Wikipedia doesn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_acronyms:_B#BR).

Comment: I agree that BR seems better, but a quick search through my emails looked like pretty 50/50 between the two spellings.

Comment: There is a frequency-of-use estimate in the AcronymFinder article. I'd just add (once more) that most of AF's listings are of what are usually termed initialisms (eg BBC, IMF) rather than acronyms (eg NATO, ISA, radar).